# C2DM inapp registration: unable to start service Intent

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-c2dm

OK, I really don't know what I'm lacking here. I try to get C2DM working for our application and especially handling the Broadcasts make me struggle.

We have an appwide BroadcastReceiver:

```
public final class AppBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    //get an instance if not already present
    public static AppBroadcastReceiver getInstance(final IntentFilter filter) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new GlobalBroadcastReceiver();
        }
        if (filter != null) {
            filter.addAction("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION";
            filter.addAction("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE");
            filter.addCategory("my.package.name");
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String broadcastAction = intent.getAction();
        Log.d(logTag, String.format("GlobalBroadcastReceiver::onReceive for action = %s", broadcastAction));

        if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION".equals(broadcastAction)) {
            for (final AppBroadcastListener l : listeners) {
                l.c2dmRegistration(intent);
            }
        } else if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE".equals(broadcastAction)) {
            for (final ApplBroadcastListener l : listeners) {
                l.c2dmReceive(intent);
            }
        }//else
    }//onReceive
}
```

AppBroadcastListener is an interface all our activities are implementing to assure the appropriate method are at least present. In their onResume(), onStop() methods the activities registering and unregistered themselves at the Receiver, respectively.

For testing purposes I have a Debug Activity proving me the following two methods:

```
public void sendC2DM(View v){
    Intent intent= new Intent();
    intent.setAction(com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE);
    intent.putExtra("message","Bender: \"kiss my shiny metal ass!\"");
    intent.addCategory(getPackageName() );

    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

public void registerC2DM(View v){
    Intent registrationIntent = new Intent(com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION);
    registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0)); // boilerplate
    registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", ourSenderIdregistered@googlemail.com);
    startService(registrationIntent);
}
```

And in the android.manifest I've added the follwoing lines in the `<application>`-tag:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".AppBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="my.package.name" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="my.package.name" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

So every activity we want to receive broadcast is registering itself at the BroadcastReceiver on it's onResume() and when something is happening the BroadcastReceiver will catch and call the implemented methods. E.g. ,logging the message or displaying a Toast.

However when I send a "C2DM message" I see this structure is working for self crafted broadcast. (Bender's message is popping up in a Toast) but `registerC2DM().startService(registrationIntent);` just logs:

> Unable to start service Intent {
>   act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION (has extras) }: not
>   found

I've no clue what I'm missing here. General advice seems to be: check your android.manifest (done) or: log in with the registered gmail account.
Not sure bout this. I'm logged in with my gmail account yeah but not with `ourSenderIdregistered@googlemail.com` which we put in the intent when registering. I also strongly believe this can not be the solution. (Telling all our customers to log in with this account... ehm no?!).
So I guess it's something else but I just can't find it :C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, this is really mean to spot:

If you want to register for c2dm you use

```
com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER
```

but to catch the answer to this message you have to set up you're broadcast receiver to listen to

```
com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
```

Subtle? Yes, here once again the error and the corrected version:

```
//false
public void registerC2DM(View v){
    Intent registrationIntent = new Intent(com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION);
    registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0)); // boilerplate
    registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", ourSenderIdregistered@googlemail.com);
    startService(registrationIntent);
}


//true
public void registerC2DM(View v){
    Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0)); // boilerplate
registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", ourSenderIdregistered@googlemail.com);
    startService(registrationIntent);
}
```

Smashed 3 keyboards before realising this... :)